# Jquery datepicker with allowed days depend on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Hi i have Jquery datepicker with allowed to choose coming 6 days , but need to make it depended on select option for example :
if choose some select option, i want to datepicker let me choose 10 days instead of allowed 6days and e.t.c

did anyone know how to do this ?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", minDate: -0, maxDate: "0m +0w 6d"} ).val();
    var date=Number($("#date").val());
    $("#date").change(function(){
        var date=Number($("#date").val());
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
        if(date===0)
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", minDate: -0, maxDate: "0m +0w 6d"} ).val();
        else
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", minDate: -0, maxDate: "0m +0w 15d"} ).val();
        $("#datepicker" ).datepicker("refresh");
        console.log(date);
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker().val();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <select name="da" id="date">
        <option value="0">no</option>
        <option value="1">yes</option>
    </select>
    <button id="button">button</button>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to show us your code and what you've tried.

Comment: i added code it works but what i need is to make it work with string value inside select option

Answer (score 0):

In your maxdate function is 6d defined. Maybe change it to 10d?

```
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", minDate: -0, maxDate: "0m +0w 10d"} ).val();
```

Will work. Also instead of making a .change, you can call a javascript function by adding an onClick to the radiobuttons and setting it in the function. Reload the datepicker afterwards because else it's still using the old configuration.

For example

```
<option onClick('changeto5();') value="0">no</option>
    <option onClick('changeto10();') value="1">yes</option>
```